# ZendX_JQuery or Zend_Dojo?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, dojo

In Zend_Framework there is [ZendX_JQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html) and [Zend_Dojo](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.html). I don't know which one is better and which one is easier to use if I have not much knowledge of JQuery or Dojo? I can spend time learning JQuery or Dojo, but I don't know which one is better choice for Zend Framework and why.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

None of theme. Mixing PHP code and Javascript code is a bad idea. http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Discontinuing-Maintenance-of-ZendX-JQuery-Suggest-drop-for-2-0-td3221855.html

Comment: actually, i have to agree with you on this one, but Zend_Form also discourage writing your own html forms. I was hoping there'll be a Zend JavaScript library 'hook' or practice to better integrate JavaScript with the framework.  When i say integrate i mean fitting it into the MVC structure.  I mean after all, JS is gaining popularity fast and w/ validity.

Comment: Thank you. So if ZendX_JQuery and Zend_Dojo are not good than it means that JQuery and Dojo are also not good? Is it better to use JavaScript library in Zend Framework?

Comment: i think what he tries to say is that he doesn't encourage using of the two classes, but instead actually use the JavaScript frameworks itself.  Or better worded, don't rely on classes to write javascript for u instead learn to write the js

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Dojo enthusiast and I've found Zend_Dojo to be useful (it's the reason I picked Zend in the first place).  As people have mentioned I keep the javascript and PHP separate, but it makes getting the environment set up quick and easy.