# Zend Form Radio jQuery buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework, zend-form-element, zendx

Do you know any good solution to display **Zend_Form_Element_Radio** as a jQuery buttons (like here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) - I haven't found any.
I know i could use

```
$("#elements").buttonset();
```

I thought rather about something like **ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Radio**, which IMO is missing :(

I am considering writing Form Element & View Helper for this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I am using ZendX_JQuery, but there is no component that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing it manually. The reason is, as written [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882373/zendx-jquery-or-zend-dojo/4883616#4883616), there is discussion about [Discontinuing Maintenance of ZendX JQuery - Suggest drop for 2.0](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Discontinuing-Maintenance-of-ZendX-JQuery-Suggest-drop-for-2-0-td3221855.html). So, if possible, I would recommend creating radio buttons normally, as you usually do in the zend framework. Then just embed JavaScript with `$("#elements").buttonset();` in e.g. your view as you usually would do when using JQuery radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcin - good point. For now did it your way (manually). Anyway I am still considering that having such a Form Element might be good idea. Even though I agree that auto-generated JS code for bigger client-side apps will make more harm than benefit I still think it makes sense to generate smaller widgets (like Radio Buttons) automatically.

Comment: @Marcinello. Glad to help. Since the future of ZendX_Jquery is uknown its better to wait and see what will heppen. You could also have a look at Zend_Dojo, as this is core component of ZF and it shouldn't go anywhere.